# Release pipeline using several build pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm facing the following issue: I have one git repo with a Node.js application. The application is divided into several components, namely: `server`, `client`, `microserviceA`, `microserviceB`. There is also a directory named `shared` with some sharaed code used by all the other components.

I have a pipeline for each of the components that only runs tests, which run on pull-request to master. Each pipeline only runs when the PR contains changes relevant to him, e.g. `server-ci` will run only when there were changes in the server component, etc.

Now, on merge to master, I would like to build the components and deploy them on a staging server. Currently what I have is as follows: for each component (beside the `shared`) I have another build pipeline (`<component>-build`) which on merge to master builds the corresponding component (depending on the changes made, as above). I have one Release pipeline which takes as artifacts all these build pipelines and deploys them on the staging server. So the good thing about this is that merge to master which includes only changes in `client` will build only `client` and not all the rest of the components.

The problem is, that on merge to master that contains changes to several components, I'll have more than one build pipeline running, so they will both trigger the Release pipeline. This is not desirable.

A possible solution I thought about was, to have only one `build` pipeline which runs on merge to master, but then I'd have to build ALL the components on each merge, which is inefficient.

What is the best way to deal with such situation?

Answer (score 0):

In the release stage settings you can configure that **Number of parallel deployments** will be 1:

[image]